# Deleting word using [:word:] gives: Invalid character class name

Tags: regex, unix, ubuntu, sed

I'm running this `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's/\/[[:word:]]+//g' *.csv
```

and in `*.csv` files I have something like:

```
name/name, val1, val2
name2/name2, val3, val4
etc
```

I want delete the one `name` and `/` so to obtain `name, val1, val2`....
But I obtain this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: Invalid character class name
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` is supporting [POSIX regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html). POSIX simply doesn't define a character class `[:word:]` and so doesn't `sed`.

You can use the following command:

```
sed 's~/[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}~~' file
```

It is using the character class `[:alnum:]` which matches letters and numbers. The `+` quantifier you were using doesn't exist in POSIX regular expressions. You need to use `\{1,\}` to express *one or more*.

Answer (score 2):

There is no character class named `[:word:]`, hence the error message regarding invalid character class name.

Presumably, you are trying to remove `/name` portion from input, if so do:

```
sed -E 's_/[^,]*__' file.csv
```

Here we have used `_` as the `sed`'s `s` (substitution) operator delimiter.

**Example:**

```
% sed -E 's_/[^,]*__' <<<'name/name, val1, val2'
name, val1, val2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `cut` or `awk` for this, assuming you want to delete everything up to and including `/` from the lines...

```
$ cat ip.txt 
name/name, val1, val2
name2/name2, val3, val4

$ cut -d/ -f2 ip.txt 
name, val1, val2
name2, val3, val4

$ awk -F/ '{print $2}' ip.txt 
name, val1, val2
name2, val3, val4
```